# JS/PHP Mail handler radio buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Now I have been trying to get this JS mail handler to work with radio buttons but have had no luck.

I have the form working with no radio button but as soon as I add them it stops responding I believe that it is the JS side is the issue as I am new to JS.

By stops responding when you click send nothing happens. JS still does validation for all other fields but does not send the form to email.

Hope this makes sense as it is late will defiantly read over this tomorrow to clear things.

Anyway here is the code I am working with any help is greatly appreciated.

Forms.js:

```
//forms
;(function($){
    $.fn.forms=function(o){
        return this.each(function(){
            var th=$(this)
                ,_=th.data('forms')||{
                    errorCl:'error',
                    emptyCl:'empty',
                    invalidCl:'invalid',
                    notRequiredCl:'notRequired',
                    successCl:'success',
                    successShow:'4000',
                    mailHandlerURL:'bat/MailHandler.php',
                    ownerEmail:'support@template-help.com',
                    stripHTML:true,
                    smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                    targets:'input,textarea,select',
                    controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                    validate:true,
                    rx:{
                        ".topic":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:select'  },
                                                    ".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".state":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
                        ".phone":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".fax":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".message":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'textarea'}
                    },
                    preFu:function(){
                        _.labels.each(function(){
                            var label=$(this),
                                inp=$(_.targets,this),
                                defVal=inp.val(),
                                trueVal=(function(){
                                            var tmp=inp.is('input')?(tmp=label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/),!!tmp&&!!tmp[1]&&tmp[1]):inp.html()
                                            return defVal==''?defVal:tmp
                                        })()
                            trueVal!=defVal
                                &&inp.val(defVal=trueVal||defVal)
                            label.data({defVal:defVal})                             
                            inp
                                .bind('focus',function(){
                                    inp.val()==defVal
                                        &&(inp.val(''),_.hideEmptyFu(label),label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                })
                                .bind('blur',function(){
                                    _.validateFu(label)
                                    if(_.isEmpty(label))
                                        inp.val(defVal)
                                        ,_.hideErrorFu(label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))                                          
                                })
                                .bind('keyup',function(){
                                    label.hasClass(_.invalidCl)
                                        &&_.validateFu(label)
                                })
                            label.find('.'+_.errorCl+',.'+_.emptyCl).css({display:'block'}).hide()
                        })
                        _.success=$('.'+_.successCl,_.form).hide()
                    },
                    isRequired:function(el){                            
                        return !el.hasClass(_.notRequiredCl)
                    },
                    isValid:function(el){                           
                        var ret=true
                        $.each(_.rx,function(k,d){
                            if(el.is(k))
                                ret=d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())                                      
                        })
                        return ret                          
                    },
                    isEmpty:function(el){
                        var tmp
                        return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                    },
                    validateFu:function(el){                            
                        el.each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                                ,req=_.isRequired(th)
                                ,empty=_.isEmpty(th)
                                ,valid=_.isValid(th)                                

                            if(empty&&req)
                                _.showEmptyFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))
                            else
                                _.hideEmptyFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))

                            if(!empty)
                                if(valid)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                else
                                    _.showErrorFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))                             
                        })
                    },
                    getValFromLabel:function(label){
                        var val=$('input,textarea',label).val()
                            ,defVal=label.data('defVal')                                
                        return label.length?val==defVal?'nope':val:'nope'
                    }
                    ,submitFu:function(){
                        _.validateFu(_.labels)                          
                        if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                                data:{
topic:_.getValFromLabel($('.topic',_.form)),
                                    name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
                                    email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
                                    phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
                                    fax:_.getValFromLabel($('.fax',_.form)),
                                    state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
                                    message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
                                    owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                    stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                                },
                                success: function(){
                                    _.showFu()
                                }
                            })          
                    },
                    showFu:function(){
                        _.success.slideDown(function(){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                _.success.slideUp()
                                _.form.trigger('reset')
                            },_.successShow)
                        })
                    },
                    controlsFu:function(){
                        $(_.controls,_.form).each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                            th
                                .bind('click',function(){
                                    _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                    return false
                                })
                        })
                    },
                    showErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideDown()
                    },
                    hideErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    showEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideDown()
                        _.hideErrorFu(label)
                    },
                    hideEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    init:function(){
                        _.form=_.me                     
                        _.labels=$('label',_.form)

                        _.preFu()

                        _.controlsFu()

                        _.form
                            .bind('submit',function(){
                                if(_.validate)
                                    _.submitFu()
                                else
                                    _.form[0].submit()
                                return false
                            })
                            .bind('reset',function(){
                                _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)                                   
                                _.labels.each(function(){
                                    var th=$(this)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                    _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                                })
                            })
                        _.form.trigger('reset')
                    }
                }
            _.me||_.init(_.me=th.data({forms:_}))
            typeof o=='object'
                &&$.extend(_,o)
        })
    }
})(jQuery)
$(window).load(function(){  
             $('#contact-form').forms({
         ownerEmail:'#'
         })
```

MailHandler.php

```
<?php
    $owner_email = $_POST["owner_email"];
    $headers = 'From:' . $_POST["email"];
    $subject = 'A message from your site visitor ' . $_POST["name"];
    $messageBody = "";

    if($_POST['name']!='nope'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>Visitor: ' . $_POST["name"] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['email']!='nope'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['state']!='nope'){        
        $messageBody .= '<p>State: ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['phone']!='nope'){        
        $messageBody .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }   
    if($_POST['fax']!='nope'){      
        $messageBody .= '<p>Fax Number: ' . $_POST['fax'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['message']!='nope'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    }

    if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
        $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
    }

    try{
        if(!mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)){
            throw new Exception('mail failed');
        }else{
            echo 'mail sent';
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage() ."\n";
    }
?>
```

Form

```
  form id="contact-form" action="/MailHandler.php">
    <div class="success">
         Contact form submitted! <strong>We have received your email and will be with you within 24 hours.</strong>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label class="part">
                 <p>A</p><input type="radio" name="part" id="part" value="a">
                 <p>B</p><input type="radio" name="part" id="part" value="b">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="name">
            <input type="text" value="Your name">
            <br>
            <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span><span class="empty">*This field is required.</span></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="phone">
            <input type="tel" value="Telephone (Please include country code)">
            <br>
            <span class="error">*This is not a valid phone number.</span><span class="empty">*This field is required.</span></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="email">
            <input type="email" value="Email">
            <br>
            <span class="error">*This is not a valid email address.</span><span class="empty">*This field is required.</span></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="message">
            <textarea>Message</textarea>
            <br>
            <span class="error">*The message is too short.</span><span class="empty">*This field is required.</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons-wrapper">
            <a class="btn btn-1" data-type="reset">Clear</a><a class="btn btn-1" data-type="submit">Send</a>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting into Stack Overflow, to help you further with your issue we probably need more details: by "it stops responding" what do you exactly mean? Are you getting any error messages? If you can post also this would certainly help other programmers to quickly identify your problem.

Comment: Hi MacK thanks for the reply by stops responding I have added to the main post but will say it again here. without the radio buttons it will send the email but once added it does not send. Once adding the radio buttons the validation works for other fields but the send button does nothing.

Comment: try deleting the whitespace here
< input type="radio" name="part" id="part" value="a"> before input and after < (definettly an error, not sure if its the cause, this kind of error will or will not be given notice depending on a lot of things)

Comment: The whitespace was just on here took be about 5 mins to figure out i need 4 spaces to show code

Comment: Have you used  the Firefox Firebug add-on to see if you have any JS errors using the script tab?

Comment: Well JS is my weak point, but I have picked up that the JS script is changing the value of the radio button to nothing then placing the value of the first button in both.

Comment: I see that you mentioned you're new to JS, did you write any of it? Because it looks like you copied and pasted the entire JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the plugin you are using is not setup to handle radio inputs.

Its not too hard to modify though.

You need to change 3 parts of the plugin. You also need to add the `.error` and `.empty` elements to the `.part` label

Firstly add this....

```
        <label class="part">
             <p>A</p><input type="radio" name="part" id="part" value="a">
             <p>B</p><input type="radio" name="part" id="part" value="b">
            <br/>
            <span class="error">* Error occurred</span><span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
        </label>
```

With that added you can see that the form is not sending due to it believing there are errors (it thinks the radios are empty).

This would cause me to investigate the `isEmpty()` function in the plugin.

I modified this bit of the plugin to look like this...

```
               isEmpty:function(el){
                    var targets = el.find(_.targets);
                    if(targets.length > 1 && targets.is("input[type='radio']")){
                        var checked = targets.filter(":checked");
                        if(checked.length){
                            return false;
                        }else{
                            return true;
                        }
                    }else{
                        var tmp
                        return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                    }
                }
```

The plugin now checks if there is more than one input found within the label and if these inputs are radios. If so it checks if one of the radios has been `:checked`. If they have then it shouldn't be considered empty and returns true thus stopping the error message.

The second modification needed would be to add the label with the class `.part` to the data that is sent via ajax to the server. this is found in the `submitFu()` function. I modified it as follows...

```
                    submitFu:function(){
                        _.validateFu(_.labels)
                        if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                                data:{
                                topic:_.getValFromLabel($('.topic',_.form)),
                                    name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
                                    email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
                                    phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
                                    fax:_.getValFromLabel($('.fax',_.form)),
                                    state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
                                    message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
                                    owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                    part:_.getValFromLabel($('.part',_.form)),
                                    stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                                },
                                success: function(){
                                    _.showFu()
                                }
                            })
                    }
```

This is the bit you need to add...

```
part:_.getValFromLabel($('.part',_.form)),
```

Now the data shoud get sent to the server. But.... It wasnt being sent. So then we have to look into the function `getValFromLabel()` to see why.

This again was not setup to handle radio buttons. So after a slight modification...

```
                   getValFromLabel:function(label){
                        var target = $('input,textarea',label);
                        if(target.length > 1 && target.is("input[type='radio']")){
                            var val = target.filter(":checked").val() || nope;
                            return val;
                        }else{
                            var val=$('input,textarea',label).val()
                                ,defVal=label.data('defVal')
                            return label.length?val==defVal?'nope':val:'nope'
                        }
                    }
```

Again we are checking if the input in the label is a radio and if so returning the value of the `:checked` one.

Success.

You can now fill out the form and hit submit and the data from the radio gets posted to the server. :)

Its worth noting though that this can be done in much less code by using html5 validation. Adding the attr `required="required"` to the inputs that are required and `type="email"` for emails `type="url"` for urls etc. And then using jquerys `$("form").serialize();` to grab the form data to post via ajax.

Anywho. Heres the whole modified plugin.

```
//forms
(function($){
    $.fn.forms=function(o){
        return this.each(function(){
            var th=$(this)
                ,_=th.data('forms')||{
                    errorCl:'error',
                    emptyCl:'empty',
                    invalidCl:'invalid',
                    notRequiredCl:'notRequired',
                    successCl:'success',
                    successShow:'4000',
                    mmailHandlerURL:'bat/MailHandler.php',
                    ownerEmail:'support@template-help.com',
                    stripHTML:true,
                    smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                    targets:'input,textarea,select',
                    controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                    validate:true,
                    rx:{
                        ".topic":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'select'  },
                        ".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".state":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
                        ".phone":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".fax":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".message":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'textarea'}
                    },
                    preFu:function(){
                        _.labels.each(function(){
                            var label=$(this),
                                inp=$(_.targets,this),
                                defVal=inp.val(),
                                trueVal=(function(){
                                            var tmp=inp.is('input')?(tmp=label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/),!!tmp&&!!tmp[1]&&tmp[1]):inp.html()
                                            return defVal==''?defVal:tmp
                                        })()
                            trueVal!=defVal
                                &&inp.val(defVal=trueVal||defVal)
                            label.data({defVal:defVal})
                            inp
                                .bind('focus',function(){
                                    inp.val()==defVal
                                        &&(inp.val(''),_.hideEmptyFu(label),label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                })
                                .bind('blur',function(){
                                    _.validateFu(label)
                                    if(_.isEmpty(label))
                                        inp.val(defVal)
                                        ,_.hideErrorFu(label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                })
                                .bind('keyup',function(){
                                    label.hasClass(_.invalidCl)
                                        &&_.validateFu(label)
                                })
                            label.find('.'+_.errorCl+',.'+_.emptyCl).css({display:'block'}).hide()
                        })
                        _.success=$('.'+_.successCl,_.form).hide()
                    },
                    isRequired:function(el){
                        return !el.hasClass(_.notRequiredCl)
                    },
                    isValid:function(el){
                        var ret=true
                        $.each(_.rx,function(k,d){
                            if(el.is(k))
                                ret=d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())
                        })
                        return ret
                    },
                    isEmpty:function(el){
                        var targets = el.find(_.targets);
                        if(targets.length > 1 && targets.is("input[type='radio']")){
                            var checked = targets.filter(":checked");
                            if(checked.length){
                                return false;
                            }else{
                                return true;
                            }
                        }else{
                            var tmp
                            return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                        }
                    },
                    validateFu:function(el){
                        el.each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                                ,req=_.isRequired(th)
                                ,empty=_.isEmpty(th)
                                ,valid=_.isValid(th)
                            if(empty&&req)
                                _.showEmptyFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))
                            else
                                _.hideEmptyFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))

                            if(!empty)
                                if(valid)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                else
                                    _.showErrorFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))
                        })
                    },
                    getValFromLabel:function(label){
                        var target = $('input,textarea',label);
                        if(target.length > 1 && target.is("input[type='radio']")){
                            var val = target.filter(":checked").val() || nope;
                            return val;
                        }else{
                            var val=$('input,textarea',label).val()
                                ,defVal=label.data('defVal')
                            return label.length?val==defVal?'nope':val:'nope'
                        }
                    }
                    ,submitFu:function(){
                        _.validateFu(_.labels)
                        if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                                data:{
topic:_.getValFromLabel($('.topic',_.form)),
                                    name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
                                    email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
                                    phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
                                    fax:_.getValFromLabel($('.fax',_.form)),
                                    state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
                                    message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
                                    owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                    part:_.getValFromLabel($('.part',_.form)),
                                    stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                                },
                                success: function(){
                                    _.showFu()
                                }
                            })
                    },
                    showFu:function(){
                        _.success.slideDown(function(){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                _.success.slideUp()
                                _.form.trigger('reset')
                            },_.successShow)
                        })
                    },
                    controlsFu:function(){
                        $(_.controls,_.form).each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                            th
                                .bind('click',function(){
                                    _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                    return false
                                })
                        })
                    },
                    showErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideDown()
                    },
                    hideErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    showEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideDown()
                        _.hideErrorFu(label)
                    },
                    hideEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    init:function(){
                        _.form=_.me
                        _.labels=$('label',_.form)

                        _.preFu()

                        _.controlsFu()

                        _.form
                            .bind('submit',function(){
                                if(_.validate)
                                    _.submitFu()
                                else
                                    _.form[0].submit()
                                return false
                            })
                            .bind('reset',function(){
                                _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)
                                _.labels.each(function(){
                                    var th=$(this)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                    _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                                })
                            })
                        _.form.trigger('reset')
                    }
                }
            _.me||_.init(_.me=th.data({forms:_}))
            typeof o=='object'
                &&$.extend(_,o)
        })
    }
})(jQuery)
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#contact-form').forms({
         ownerEmail:'#'
    });
})
```

Hope it helps.

Cheers, Ed